# Taking screenshot of partial area in Unity?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, unity-game-engine, screen-capture

My game lets you dress up your character. I would like to save off that image (but not the rest of the 800x600 screen) to a file. According to the help, I can use Application.CaptureScreen() to capture the full screen but how does one capture just one part of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want full control over what area you want to screenshot, I would recommend setting up a new camera with a `RenderTexture`. This will enable a more flexible way of controlling your composition for your screenshots. Like the Avatar Creator on Xbox360.

1. Create a new camera and align it to fit the image and composition of choice.
2. Add a `RenderTexture`
3. Use `ReadPixels` to read from the RenderTexture into a `Texture2D` and save using `EncodeToPNG`.
4. Save to disk or upload to server

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-RenderTexture.html

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.EncodeToPNG.html